# .tmLanguage.json RegEx expression not working/leads to no syntax highlighting

Tags: json, regex, tmlanguage

I want to highlight everything after "print" as a string, the problem is that this leads to no highlighting even though the regex, in theory, should work.

As an example replacing `"match":` with `"begin":"somestring"` and typing `somestring` into vscode, works.

This is the JSON for the specific section:

```json
"afterprint": {
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "string.quoted.double",
                    "match": "(?<=print)(?s)(.*$)"
                }
            ]
        }
```

[regex101.com example/test](https://regex101.com/r/B5jZpu/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get this working on my side by removing the `(?s)`, I am unsure why this is the case, maybe a bug or restricted regex. Anyways it solves your question, as everything after `print` gets highlighted

```
"afterprint": {
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "string.quoted.double",
                    "match": "(?<=print)(.*$)"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Just to mention, other regex hasn't worked for me as well in `foo.tmLanguage.json` I have still not solved this "mystery".